# How to extract every bold words in a html text

Tags: html, xml, oracle

I have a text like that.

```
<div>
    blabla <b> BOLD </b> babla <b> BOLD2</b> blabla
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:30px">-</td>
       <td>blabla <b>BOLD3</b></td>
  </tr> 
</div>
```

I want to extract the word between the b tag. But there is several path.

```
SELECT  t1,t2
       FROM mytext,
            XMLTABLE (
                '/div'
                PASSING xmltype (raw_text.inhalt)
                COLUMNS t2     VARCHAR2 (1000) PATH './b',              --
                        t1     VARCHAR2 (1000) PATH './table/tr/td/b'))
```

> [Error] Execution (11: 1): ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your HTML is valid XML (which is not always the case as it needs a single root node and all opening tags to be closed) then given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytext (rawtext  CLOB);

INSERT INTO mytext (rawtext) VALUES (
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict" >
  <div>
    blabla <b> BOLD </b> babla <b> BOLD2</b> blabla
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:30px">-</td>
        <td>blabla <b>BOLD3</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>'
);
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT bold
FROM   mytext m
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE (
         XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict'),
         '//b'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(m.rawtext)
         COLUMNS bold VARCHAR2(1000) PATH './text()'
       )
```

Which outputs:

> | BOLD |
> | --- |
> | `BOLD` |
> | `BOLD2` |
> | `BOLD3` |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d5beca107393dbb73c2c22d706873999)*

Answer (score 0):

This version works too. And you don't have to add more html markup.
You only have to remove `XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict')`

```
CREATE TABLE mytext (
  rawtext  CLOB
);

INSERT INTO mytext (rawtext) VALUES (
'<div>
    blabla <b> BOLD </b> babla <b> BOLD2</b> blabla
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:30px">-</td>
        <td>blabla <b>BOLD3</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>'
);

SELECT bold
FROM   mytext m
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE (
         '//b'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(m.rawtext)
         COLUMNS bold VARCHAR2(1000) PATH './text()'
       )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0889004081eb0c86bf3b869d953cf04e

Comment: This is effectively a link-only answer. You should copy the contents of the db<>fiddle into your answer so that it is still valid if the link dies.